# extract wsdl from c# winforms client

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, asmx

I have a client that was successfully calling a webservice. the webservice was changed then the changes removed. but now the compiled c# winforms client cannot call the webservice.

Can I extract the wsdl the client is expecting to compare with the actual wsdl???

Comment: Did you add the service reference manually or with the wizard in Visual Studio/Sharp Develop/Mono Develop/etc? If you did not do it manually then did you refresh the web service reference in your project (right-click the web reference and click 'Update Web Reference')?

Comment: this client is compiled. it is out in the field an older version.

Comment: Although the changes were removed, was the service re-deployed? In fact, why not just redeploy the original code - roll back the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you click the "show all files" button in your Solution Explorer, your web reference will then become expandable. The wsdl will then be viewable (expand the reference).